# как облегчить сборку vuejs проекта webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Webpack при сборке проекта на vue.js собирает в build assets кучу файлов
[image]

Но из них на странице подключается лишь app, vendor и manifest

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'assets',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: false,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css']
  }
}
```

Вся сборка занимает минут 10, можно ли как то "облегчить" этот процесс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть у вас npm пакеты компилируются?

Попробуйте добавить в конфиг webpack:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю вашей специфики и сложности, но просто собрать проект использующий vue.js у меня не занимает много времени, мои примеры настроек ниже.
Пример моего конфига webpack:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './js/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

вот пример app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Home from './Components/Home.vue'
import Users from './Components/Users.vue'
import Calculator from './Components/Calculate.vue'

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/users/:id?', component: Users },
    { path: '/calculator', component: Calculator }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

Vue.component('index', require('./Components/Test.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```